# Keywords to find good tutorials

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I want to create multiple winform from a SQL Database with multiple realtionships and can't find a good turotrial. My end goal for this front end application is to have:

1. read data to 6-7 forms and the forms to be able to insert,update,delete
2. 1 of the forms will have a tab
3. button to go to the next/previous/first/last row that has data from a few different tables with relationships.
4. The forms will link to one complaint from tables below
5. Buttons will lead data-entry person to get to each of the forms.
6. Each form will update, insert, delete, or read from SQL Server with the tables listed below.

I've watched many videos similar to the link below but the problem is that these videos don't show the form reading the data from SQL Server, then it being searchable to find a "Complaint" to update or delete. You have to manually enter in a data for it to be updated or delete for these videos.

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3FpM8f2suI
```

The only thing with this is that, most videos use datagrids or list boxes. I do not want to use a list box and datagris.  I just want to use a textbox for each field. I've also heard entityframework is the way I should go.

What I have are:

1. Customer
2. Customer Service Rep
3. Notes
4. Complaints
5. Complaint Allegations

All tables are either left joined or joined to the Complaints table by the CompID.

My question is, am I searching for videos with wrong keywords? I am using:

```
1. Update, Insert, Read, Delete WinForm C# SQL Server
2. C# frontend and SQL Server Backend
3. Winform C# and SQL Server
```

Comment: This is very basic question you ask, there are lots of resources in internet, browse you-tube video tutorials, code project, You can't get all answers in one single web site you must have to refer several web sites.

Comment: The keywords your using are fine...

Comment: I would added "layered application".  example : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658127.aspx

Comment: I would HIGHLY recommend ISBN : 1935182501.  This will help you not design spaghetti code right from the start.

Comment: The tutorial has inline sql.  And the "form1" knows about the sqlclient.  Aka, no layers.  This is only the most basic of tutorials.  You should at the very very least have 3 layers.

Comment: @granadaCoder thank you so much for all the references and comments. If you have any other reads please let me know!

Comment: Thanks for assuring my searching methods @Ezi

Comment: @granadaCoder, do you have any recommendations on a beginner level of C# writer? These readings seem to be a bit advanced for me as I am still learning c#.

Comment: This isn't too awfully bad.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36847/Three-Layer-Architecture-in-C-NET   .. I understand,...you're  new.  The tension point is "getting something running" vs.... learning bad patterns that paint you into a corner down the road.

Comment: That is my goal. To not learn bad patterns! @granadaCoder. Thank you again.

Comment: Here's a decent one too : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7QbeJUosWM

Comment: this dude...seems to be on-target with basic stuff : https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=c%23+urdu

Comment: @granadaCoder, the second youtube link appears to be in Urdu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use lazy load better for you load the data in the tab form when ever you need it, but if you need to do it use `HashTable<fromName, List<YourDBObject>>` load this data in the time of the first form load and then map it to the different form when the user change  the tab